# Accessing Form1 Buttons from other class C#

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to access the Form1 Buttons from another class.

I tried like this:

```
class X{
 public void Check() {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        if (form.button1.color == Color.Black) {
            //do something
        }
}
```

And I got this error: `'Form1.button1' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Mildly curious why you would be interested in a button (UI) colour? Presumably, there is a related datasource or object that might influence the colour? In which case, it would be the state of this object that would be interest, rather than a fickle button state.

Comment: I'm a beginner in programming and I'm trying to create a Renju game, with a list of buttons. And for example, when but1,but2,but3,but4 and but5 (which are in a row) are black/white, the player will win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change some properties of an already displayed form you need the instance of that form.
But accessing directly an inner component of the form is a bad practice and probably this is the reason for the default value on the property Modifiers to be Private. If you change this property to Public then you can access the inner button control

However I suggest you to use a more OOP approach. 
First create a public property in Form1 class that returns the ForeColor or BackColor of your button to anyone that want to know it without giving full access to the whole button

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Color CurrentColor 
    {
        get { return button1.ForeColor; }
    }

}
```

Now in class X pass the instance of the current  Form1 to the Check method and use the CurrentColor property

```
class X
{
    public void Check(Form1 current) 
    {
        if (current.CurrentColor == Color.Black) 
        {
             .....do something...    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that button on the Form class marked as a private member. If you open Form1.Designer.cs file, you will see:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

So you can't use button1 from other classes. If you want to do it, change private to public:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

And after that you can to use it in other classes:

```
class X
{
    void Check()
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.button1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    }
}
```

You can read about access modifiers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers)

P.S.
Also I can recommend you use [MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp) pattern to maintain your application